# How to flag a question which is an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

In the suggested edits review queue I came to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820652/link-error-cannot-open-input-file-when-building-openalpr-on-visual-studio). Seems that it's trying to answer a different [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528331/link-error-cannot-open-input-file-when-building-openalpr-on-visual-studio). In their own words the OP of the first question tells:

> Note this is a solution I guess to will help the [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528331/link-error-cannot-open-input-file-when-building-openalpr-on-visual-studio) here
>   I had no rights to post this answer there
>   hope it helps.

So I flag this question with a custom flag telling:

> This is an answer for another closed question referenced in this
>   question itself. It has nonsense as a question.

But the flag is declined with the follow reason:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and
>   resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of
>   standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

I review the flag link and I don't see how to flag this with a standard flag, so IMO a custom flag is necessary for this case. Maybe I'm wrong so here is my first question: *How is supposed to flag this kind of question?*

Despiste all of this in fact IMO the question seems wrong so maybe I flagged it wrong but anyways the question probably needs to be removed but it's still alive, so my second question is: *Is it correct to flag again the same question trying to flag with another kind of flag? If yes what is it the correct flag to use?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can flag (in fact, vote to close) the question as 'unclear what you're asking':

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. *As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.* See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

(emphasis mine).

You can also use a custom off-topic reason. This might *feel* like a custom flag, but it isn't.

Doing so will allow the community (to be precise, other members with 3k reputation) to deal with the question, instead of 'wasting' ♦ moderator time.

> Is it correct to flag again the same question trying to flag with another kind of flag?

Yes, this is no problem at all.

Comment: I disagree with closing this as 'unclear', but the rest is good advice.

Comment: So a better action is vote to close, however the flag reason itself it's not wrong isn't? (ok it can waste moderator time, but I think the same time is wasted declining the flag or deleting the question which IMO is the proper action here). Anyways the next time I'll vote to close this kind of question instead of flagging it, thanks for your advice :)

Comment: @albciff in general, you shouldn't involve ♦ moderators for things you can solve yourself (with help of other users, of course). Of course it's a waste of time declining the flag, but it will hopefully save them some time in the future.

Comment: @Glorfindel but a accepted flag with a comment explaining how to deal with this in the future could be also great. Thanks for your time and explanation again :).

Comment: @albciff unfortunately, that isn't possible with the ♦ moderator tools (so I've been told).

Comment: @Glorfindel It's possible to leave a comment along with the helpful flag. :)

Comment: Oh, then I have been told wrongly. I'll try to find out where. Or maybe it's a recent addition.